# AWS CI/CD for ECS fargate deployment using Developer tools(CodeBuild, CodePipeline, Code Deploy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I had CI/CD(Docker publish plugin for build and shell script for creation of ELB, ECS Cluster, ECS Task Definition, ECS service creation etc) pipeline created in Jenkins with AWS CLI(shell script). That is well and good. 
But now we are trying to get rid of Jenkins and create a complete CI/CD in AWS itself using AWS Developer tools. For building of image i created CodeBuild project, but deployment script(shell script for creating ELB, ECS Cluser,TD,Service creation etc) where i need to place? i am not getting.

Could you please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to develop a pipeline (CodePipeline) with following stages:

`Git` -> `CodeBuild` (build action in CodePipeline, builds the image, publishes to image repo e.g. ECR and writes a file 'imagedefinitions.json' required for next action) -> `ECS` (deploy action in Codepipeline, uses 'imagedefinitions.json' to deploy your service to Fargate).

This tutorial beautifully summarizes the whole process, please follow it to know all the pieces involved:

- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html